# Are there any libraries in Python Pandas or statmodels to distinguish between addictive and multiplicative time series data

Tags: time-series

When I did research on identifying addictive models and multiplicative models in time series data, many sources are stressing on visual identification by looking at the graph.

There are more reliable methods than this however all explained by Statistical calculations. [Additive vs Multiplicative model in Time Series Data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/additive-vs-multiplicative-model-in-time-series-data)

Are there any python Pandas or statsmodels or any other libraries that can do the identification part